# How can I use similar routes with different namespaces in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-8

I have a problem with routes in Laravel 8.
I have 2 controllers with the same controller name and same function name but in different namespaces.

Route 1:

```
Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {

    //Frontend Category Route
    Route::get('{main}/{slug}', 'CategoryController@one')->name('category.1');

});
```

Route 2:

```
Route::namespace('Backend')->group(function () {

    //Backend Category Route
    Route::get('categories/{level?}/{id?}', 'CategoryController@index')->name('categories');

});
```

Namespace line of Category Controller in Frontend:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;
```

Namespace line of Category Controller in Backend:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;
```

**When I call "index" function in backend category controller the function named "one" in frontend category controller works.**

Is there any solution other than changing the controller name?

PHP Version: 7.3.10
Laravel Version: 8.83.13

Comment: that first route has 2 wildcards so it will catch any 2 segment route .... this is just a route order issue / route design issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [prefix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes) both route groups like this:

```php
  /* --- Frontend --- */
  Route::prefix('/backend')->namespace('Backend')->group(function(){
    Route::get('categories/{level?}/{id?}', 'CategoryController@index')->name('categories');
  });

  /* --- Frontend --- */
  Route::prefix('/front')->namespace('Frontend')->group(function(){
    Route::get('{main}/{slug}', 'CategoryController@one')->name('category.1');
  });
```

If you don't want to prefix the "front" routes, just put the backend routes on top. Backend routes will be evaluated first and if there's no match, the requested url will fall to the frontend routes.

Comment: I put the backend routes at the top, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @HelloWorld You're welcome! You should still consider prefixing the "category.1" route with something to avoid future conflicts with routes again

Comment: I will do. Thank you.